# i created two buttons inside the while loop.while clicking that button i am getting last row of database.i want corrspoinding datas

Tags: php

```
while($s=mysql_fetch_row($q))
{
echo "<table width=90% bgcolor='#6CDAF5' align=center>
    <tr><th align=left> Bug $i: </tr>
    <tr><td>Username: <td> $s[0] </td></tr>
    <tr><td>User email-id: <td>$s[1] </td></tr>
    <tr><td>User Contact-no :<td>$s[2] </td></tr>
    <tr><td>Bug: <td><textarea rows=5 cols=40 name=bug>$s[3]</textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Bug-Reason: <td><textarea rows=5 cols=40  name=text1>$s[4]</textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Bug-Solution:<td><textarea rows=5 cols=40 name=text2>$s[5]</textarea></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Updated-date:<td><input type=text value='$s[6]' name=date></td></tr>
    <tr><td width=100% align=right colspan=2><input type=button name=addbug value='add this bug with main bugs' OnClick=validate()><input type=button name=delete value='delete this bug' OnClick=delete()></tr>
    </table><br>";
    $i++;
}
```

here i fetched all rows from database by using select * from troubleshoot; query...  each and every table contains two buttons..  after displaying tables in the browser,, while clicking button i am getting last table values only.. how to get corressponding button values while the clicking button

Comment: what exactly you want..?

Comment: do the bugs have some unique id?  You are incrementing $i which doesn't necessarily reference a bug, just its position in the results returned from the db.

Comment: i fetched some rows from database.. then i am putting that each rows value in a table as per above coding.. each and every table contains two buttons as "add with main bug" and "delete bug"...If i click this buttons it will go to another php file and here corrosponding datas will displayed.. after displayed in the browser i clicked first table "add with main bug" button"... it went to next page.. In that page thr didnt display first table bug and reason and solution.. thr last table bug and reason and solution only displayed.. i have to get corresponding datas while click the add with main bug

Comment: plls help me... sry if u couldnt understand me...

Comment: Can you post the rest of your php? Also the validate()  or delete() function would be helpful. It's hard to guess what your codes doing.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16728936/how-to-give-specification-for-button-in-php-when-it-is-in-while-loop ... ... ... OH WAIT, it's still you, asking the same question with the same awful format! are you kidding me?

Answer (score 1):

You want to be able to get the id when deleting?

try something like,

```
OnClick=delete('".$i."')
```

and

```
OnClick=validate('".$i."')
```

Comment: BTW $i is just a counter.  If you have some bug id you'd be better off using that.  OnClick=delete('".$s['bug_id']."')

Comment: i didnt get clearly sir,, can u explain me briefly.. hw can i pass that corresponding datas by using above method