# how to give specification for button in php when it is in while loop

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
echo "<html><form name=form1 method=post>";
$c = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("test", $c);
$query = mysql_query("select * from age");
while ($s = mysql_fetch_row($query))
{
    echo "<table><tr><td>Name   :<textarea rows=5 cols=5 name=name>$s[0] </textarea></td></tr><tr><td>Age   :<textarea rows=5 cols=5 name=age>$s[1] </textarea></td></tr><tr><td><input type=submit value='click' name=submit></td></tr></table>";
}
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $age = $_POST['age'];
    echo "name is $name"." age is $age";
}
echo "</form></html>";
?>
```

here in the test table there are 4 entries present with name and age....   I am fetching that name and age and putting that in textarea and I created one button for each table.. while click that button I am getting last entry in database.. but I want corresponding name and age.. please help me

Comment: provide table structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are using one big `<form>` element for all your entries. When sending that form, the actual values get overridden many times and you just see the last one.

To solve this, you could, e.g., make a form out of every entry like this:

```
echo "<html>";

$c = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("test", $c);
$query = mysql_query("select * from age");

while ($s = mysql_fetch_row($query))
{
    echo "<form method=post><table><tr><td>Name   :<textarea rows=5 cols=5 name=name>$s[0] </textarea></td></tr><tr><td>Age   :<textarea rows=5 cols=5 name=age>$s[1] </textarea></td></tr><tr><td><input type=submit value='click' name=submit></td></tr></table></form>";
}

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $age=$_POST['age'];
    echo "name is $name";
    echo "age is $age";
}
// ... rest of the code ...
```

<sub>Anyway, the `mysql` functions, you use, are deprecated. Have a look at [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [`mysqli`](http://php.net/mysqli) as a replacement!</sub>

Comment: Try Javascript to set table element to empty string or 

use php DOMText function.

Comment: @VAISHNAVI: Please refrain from commenting any further. If you have a new question, ask it separately. Don't repeatedly comment under this answer.